# Python. Полное логирование консоли в файл

Tags: python, логирование

Я сделал своего `discord бота`, поставил его на хостинг, но столкнулся с проблемой: Там нет консоли и если произойдёт какая-то ошибка, то я не буду знать о ней.
Нашёл решение: `логирование`. Сделал, но понял, что оно сохраняет только то, что выводит функция `print()`
Как сделать так, чтобы `АБСОЛЮТНО ВСЁ` что выводится в консоль, сохранялось в файл?

Comment: Можно перенаправить *stdout* и *stderr* в определенный файл. Вот варианты с англоязычного форума: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer

Answer (score 0):

Перенаправьте **stdout** и **stderr** *(поток вывода и поток вывода ошибок)* в отдельный файл. По желанию можете завести два файла для каждого из потоков *(один для ошибок, и один для остального)*. Пример кода:

```
from sys import stdout, stderr
stdout = open("stdout.txt", "a")
stderr = open("stderr.txt", "a")
```

Добавьте это в начале файла, и простой вывод будет сохранён в файл "*stdout.txt*", а вывод ошибок в файл "*stderr.txt*".

После перезапуска программы, файл будет дописываться *(вывод с прошлого запуска не будет стёрт)*.

Comment: А если после каждого перезапуска вы хотите начинать файл заново (перезаписывать его), вместо второго аргумента "a", укажите "w".